# Open event viewer from a certain node

Tags: c#, mmc, event-viewer

What is the command to open windows event viewer displaying a particular node details?

For example if I simply use `eventvwr` command; it opens the UI with Root Node selected. I want `Application` node selected when it is opened OR any other node.

Can it be configured programatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To view the eventvwr.exe arguments simply type:

```
eventvwr /?
```

To specifically open the Application log use the command below:

```
eventvwr computername /l:"%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Application.evtx"
```

Answer (score 1):

For an Application node you'd call it as such:

```
eventvwr /c:Application
```

Comment: If you are trying to open your custom log try `eventvwr /c:"My New Service Log"`.  As an example, If it shows up under `Event Viewer->Applications and Services Logs->My New Service Log`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Your best option is to create a custom view - to filter the events from some specific apps if thats what you want. For command line, 'eventvwr /f' can be used to specify filter.