# opening Windows 7 event viewer to system logs directly using c#

Tags: c#, events, logging

Does anyone know of a way to open the Windows 7 event viewer using c# that will open directly to the system logs? I know the command line command to open the event viewer is 'eventvwr', but is there any way to program within c# to execute the program and only show the system logs found under the windows logs heading, and within that, only the errors? My idea is to click a button within my c# program and have the event log open to the system logs displaying errors so it is faster and easier for troubleshooting troubleshooting.

Comment: See the answer for examples. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784131/are-there-any-c-sharp-open-source-log-viewers?rq=1

Comment: Already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010397/open-event-viewer-from-a-certain-node: you can create a custom view and launch that using the appropriate command line.

Comment: @RichardCook Thank you, that got me much closer to what I was looking for. Ideally, I would like it display only errors when it opens, but this might have to be good enough. Thanks for your help!